# Updating of Tiles in TicTacToe game using sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

So I am creating a game using sfml in c++ and my code doesn't update the tile on which I click properly.

I used the function isTileClicked to check if a tile is clicked and update the variables  clickedTileRow and clickedTileCol to the row and column of the Tile currently clicked. I expect it to update only the tile whose indices are in accordance to the variables clickedTileRow and clickedTileCol.The issue here is that when I click a new tile it updates all previously clicked tiles as well.

the game.h file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
static int changer = 0;
class Player; 
class Game  //class to playGame
    {
        private:
        sf :: RenderWindow window;
        sf :: Texture Tex, emptyTile; 
        sf :: Sprite **sprites;
        sf :: Event clickSprite;
        int clickedTileRow, clickedTileCol;
        Player *p;

        public:
        Game(); 
        ~Game();
        sf:: Window& getWindow();
        void setSpriteMemory();
        sf :: Sprite** getSpritesArr();
        void setTexture();
        sf::Texture getTexture();
        void setBoard();
        void setPlayerMemory();
        void set_player(Player *player);
        Player* getPlayer();
        bool isTileClicked(int xCoord, int yCoord);
        void playGame();
    };
#endif// GAME_H
```

the game.cpp file is:

```
#include "game.h"
#include "player.h"

Game :: Game() : window(sf:: VideoMode(600,800), "TicTacToe")
    {
         //ask for size of board
        sprites = nullptr;
        p = nullptr;
        clickedTileRow = -1;
        clickedTileCol = -1;
    }
Game :: ~Game()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                delete sprites[i];
            }
        delete [] sprites;
    }
sf:: Window& Game :: getWindow() 
        {
            return window;
        }
void Game :: setSpriteMemory()
        {
            sprites = new sf :: Sprite*[3];
            for(int i = 0; i <3; i++)
                {
                    sprites[i] = new sf :: Sprite[3];
                }
        }
sf :: Sprite** Game :: getSpritesArr()
            {
               return this->sprites;
            }
void  Game :: setTexture()
        {
            Tex.loadFromFile("images/board.png");
            emptyTile.loadFromFile("images/board.png");
        }
sf::Texture Game :: getTexture()
        {
            return this->Tex;
        }

void Game :: setBoard()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                        {
                                sprites[i][j].setTexture(getTexture()) ;
                                sprites[i][j].setScale(0.25f,0.25f);
                                sprites[i][j].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(i * 130, j * 130));
                        }
                }
        }
    void Game :: setPlayerMemory()
        {
            p = new Player;
        }
bool Game :: isTileClicked(int xCoord, int yCoord)
    {   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        sf :: FloatRect tileBounds = sprites[i][j].getGlobalBounds();
                        if(tileBounds.contains(xCoord, yCoord))
                            {  
                                clickedTileRow = i;
                                clickedTileCol = j;
                                
                                return true;
                               
                            }                     
                    }               
            }
        clickedTileRow = -1;
        clickedTileCol = -1;   
        return false;
    }
void Game :: playGame()
        {
            while (window.isOpen())
            {
                sf::Event event;
                while (window.pollEvent(event))
                {
                    // Event handling - Check for window close event
                    if (event.type == sf :: Event :: Closed) //KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Enter
                        window.close();
                    //Check for box clicked
                    else if(event.type == sf :: Event :: MouseButtonPressed)
                        {
                            int xCoord = event.mouseButton.x;
                            int yCoord = event.mouseButton.y;
                          
                            if( isTileClicked( xCoord, yCoord ) )
                            {
                                sprites[clickedTileRow][clickedTileCol].setTexture(this->p->get_currentplayer());
                                clickedTileRow = -1;
                                clickedTileCol = -1;
                                p->change_player( changer  );
                                changer++;
                                
                            }
                        }
                    
                }

                // Update game state here (currently no updates in this example)

                // Rendering - Clear the window, draw sprites, and display
                window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {   
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {   
                        window.draw(sprites[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                window.display();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the update code and step through your code line by line looking at your variables and flow after each individual line is executed in your debugger to determine why your code is not behaving how you expected / designed it to behave. Learning how to use your debugger is an essential skill that you need to master to be a successful programmer.